# Performance scaling in MongoDB (search operations)?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use mongoDB for a large collection of documents. Everything works fine as long as the data is smaller and fits in memory, but when it doesn't, the read/search performance is terrible. For a 500-million-document collection a simple indexed query (eg. regex query on a single, indexed field) runs nearly 2 hours. This is strange - the collection size is approx. 300GB, reading it sequentially from hdd should take not more than half an hour. And since it uses index it should be even faster (the result has ~100k documents; there are about 2M of distinct values of this particular field in collection). The regex matching alone should take no more than a few seconds if done on the (distinct) index keys - simple python script matching those values takes 6secs.

As far as I see DBMS accesses disk in random order even when processing queries using such an index (similar query but with no results). I use many indexes and they all don't fit in memory in the same time, so this seems to be the problem (they use 50-60GB, the machine has 32GB of RAM). Hence, the question is: is it possible to tune up DBMS I/O methods to perform more intelligent readaheads or operation ordering?

Or maybe I should switch to something other than mongo? So far I've looked on Lucene and Cassandra and I think they don't fit my needs. My task in more details:

I want to use DB to select documents from a large number of small attribute-structures according to some requirements on their attributes. The structures are sometimes nested. I need to retrive only their identifiers for further processing but all attributes/fields are used in searches. The operations I need are conjunctions and alternatives of conditions on single fields, where the conditions are: equals to a constant, regex match (not a fulltext), plus quantifiers on substructure lists (all substructures on a list have an attribute matching regex ..., there exist a substructure with an attribute equal to ..., and so on).

The typical use is concurrent read-only operations; writes are infrequent, batch inserts (exclusive - write-only). The 500M collection is my devel/testing data, production will use up to the order of 10G of documents, 10TB of data (this is why any sugestions like 'buy more RAM' will hardly help).

Thanks for any help,
Bart

EDIT:

The .explain() output:

```js
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor orth_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 107290,
"nscannedObjects" : 107290,
"nscanned" : 250202122,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 107290,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 250202122,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 2954078,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 6193156,
"indexBounds" : {
    "orth" : [
        [
            "",
            {

            }
        ],
        [
            /[A-Z].+ski/,
            /[A-Z].+ski/
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "bart:27017",
"filterSet" : false
}
```

Log entry:

```js
2014-06-26T11:46:41.672+0200 [conn2] query nkjp_300m_noni.simple_nodes query: { query: { orth: /[A-Z].+ski/ }, $explain: true } planSummary: IXSCAN { orth: 1.0 } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:250202122 nscannedObjects:107290 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1016206 locks(micros) r:355736129 nreturned:1 reslen:1187 6193156ms
```

EDIT2:
The same query run again without any other queries in between takes 130s.

Comment: You should provide some debug info on this. I think an `explain()` output would be ideal. Also, have you determined what mongo does during these 2 hours? Are there any monitoring data we could use? log entries? How are the systems resources at that time (mem usage, io etc) ?

Comment: I'm attaching .explain() output and log entry. Mongo mainly waits, CPU usage is ~1%, disk is reading at about 1MB/s, memory is nearly full of buffers/cache.

Comment: can you show us the actual query as well?

Comment: Here it goes: `db.simple_nodes.find({'orth' : /[A-Z].+ski/}).explain()
`

Comment: is it always `/[A-Z].+ski/` or `/^[A-Z].+ski/` or `/[A-Z].+ski$/` ?

Comment: Are you matches from the begining of the string or just anywhere in the string?

Comment: This is a very difficult query to perform, there is no easy answer for this. Even with a regex prefix there is no way that MongoDB could answer this quickly.

Comment: My patterns should match the whole string. This query is just an example, the patterns are given by user, so I cannot guarantee anything like prefix. All what I expect from mongo is to load a list/tree/whatever containing keys of the index, do pattern matching on all of them and return some documents (it will read the disk randomly, but 100k random accesses don't take 2hrs).

Comment: It's not 100K random accesses it is 250202122 random accesses

Comment: So the regex matching is not done on index keys but on all document fields? Log says it uses index... Or maybe Mongo doesn't use distinct key values in index??

Comment: Sorry I meant that many index accesses, that is what's taking the time, not the loading of documents from the disk. I wrote my comment kind of quickly

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with looking closely at these three lines from your explain() output:

```
"n" : 107290,
"nscannedObjects" : 107290,
"nscanned" : 250202122,
```

Your query had to take a look at over 250M index entries in order to retrieve 107290 documents. This is a function of the relatively poor usage of indexes by regex queries. Regex queries are not great users of indexes to begin with, and without a prefix expression (like `{ orth: /^A.+ski/ }` as an example). From the documentation:

> If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular
>   expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a
>   collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular
>   expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential
>   matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a
>   “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the
>   index that fall within that range.
>
> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a
>   caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple
>   symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching
>   only against the values from the index that start with abc.
>
> Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent
>   strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these
>   expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however,
>   /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching
>   the prefix.

If that index cannot fit into memory, the search is going to be dependent on paging the index in and out of memory which is going to be very slow. This issue (you need the full index in memory and you do not have enough memory for both the index and the working set) really kills MongoDB performance.

Your options are somewhat limited:

- Add more memory - MongoDB performance is going to be severely
  impacted as long as you cannot fit your working set plus critical
  pieces of the index in memory.
- Re-factor your query to use prefix expressions - from the comments I
  see this is probably not an option but I include it to be complete.
- Move to SSD or other fast disk option - if you can't get enough
  memory and you need to pull things from disk, SSD will usually help.
  Again, this may not be feasible for you given overall database size
  but here for completeness.
- Re-factor to use text indexes - this will require more analysis and
  more in-depth knowledge of your application, schema and usage
  patterns but worth a look. Text indexes have different strengths and
  weaknesses than regex queries on regular indexes, and are not a magic
  bullet. I suspect this may not work for you given your existing use
  of regex queries but worth some experimentation.
- Move searches to a dedicated text index software package - personally
  I'd look closely at using Solr or Elasticsearch as your text search
  appliance. There are robust packages out there for keeping your
  Elasticsearch text index in sync with your MongoDB (see
  https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/). Your
  high reads, low batch writes scenario fits well with this approach
  and you have significant more flexibility with Elasticsearch to tune
  your field definitions and queries for better text search
  performance. It's also fairly straight forward to scale out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [regex documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) indexes can perform better for a regex search if the regex is a prefix expression. I think you could try that for your case.

There is also the [text-index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) but I am not sure it fits your purpose.

If those don't help, is it possible that you could try manipulating the data on write? I am thinking that if your query set is very limited and known you can add some flag data on your records as you insert them and then add indexes on them.

Comment: Patterns and other conditions come directly from user, and this is a quite frequent example. Flags will rather don't help, but I'll try storing all distinct values of such attributes aside, and then match regexps there and use some references in the main collection. But I still think the pattern matching is not the bottleneck in my case...